# Проверить на null

Tags: java, generics, null

Определите и реализуйте общий статический метод, hasNull который возвращается, true если входной массив имеет null элемент, и в false противном случае.

Sample Input 1:
String
There are elements of the array

Sample Output 1:
false

```
class ArrayUtils {

    public static <T> boolean hasNull(T[] value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `если входной массив имеет null элемент`

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае, вы проверяете сам массив на `null`, а не наличие в этом массиве `null` элементов.

Код с использованием Stream API

```
public static <T> boolean hasNull(T[] value) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(value); // Если null, то пробросить исключение
        return Arrays.stream(value)
                .anyMatch(Objects::isNull); 
    }
```

Также можно использовать цикл for-each

```
public static <T> boolean hasNull(T[] value) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(value); // Если null, то пробросить исключение
    for (T t : value) {
        if (t == null) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде ошибкой является применение условия ко всему массиву. Условие применять нужно к **элементам массива** переданного в данную функцию:

```
class ArrayUtils {

    public static <T> boolean hasNull(T[] value) {
        for (T t : value)
            if (t == null)
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] asdf = new Integer[2];
        asdf[0] = 1;

//        asdf[1] = 2; // пока эта строка закоментарен ответ будет true, если убрать комментарий, то ответ будет false

        System.out.println(hasNull(asdf));
    }
}
```